# Partition not able to understand

Tags: hive, partition

My input data is as follows:

```
1,srinivas,courtthomas,memphis
2,vindhya,courtthomas,memphis
3,srinivas,courtthomas,kolkata
4,vindhya,courtthomas,memphis
```

And I have created the following queries:

```
create EXTERNAL table seesaw (id int,name string,location string) partitioned by (address string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile LOCATION '/seesaw';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/sampledoc' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE seesaw PARTITION (address = 'Memphis');
```

when I try to fetch my query it comes as follows:

```
Select * from seesaw;                                                                     
OK
1   srinivas    courtthomas Memphis
2   vindhya courtthomas Memphis
3   srinivas    courtthomas Memphis
4   vindhya courtthomas Memphis
```

I really don't understand how all the rows have been showing memphis at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Read your code closely:

```
create EXTERNAL table seesaw (id int,name string,location string)
```

Notice that there are only three columns, `id`, `name` and `location`.

Your data, however,

```
1,srinivas,courtthomas,memphis
2,vindhya,courtthomas,memphis
3,srinivas,courtthomas,kolkata
4,vindhya,courtthomas,memphis
```

has four columns. Something's fishy here.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/sampledoc'
  OVERWRITE INTO TABLE seesaw
  PARTITION (address = 'Memphis');
```

you're asking to partition a category that only contains `courtthomas` by `Memphis`. The result is to little surprise not what you want.

Comment: Data written to the filesystem is serialized as text with columns separated by ^A and rows separated by newlines can you please tell me what does that mean ? I found it in the hive manual. especially what does ^A means ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using external table, you will need to manually create folders for each partition, i.e in your case - create two folders [address=Memphis] and [address=kolkata] AND copy the corresponding input data files under the corresponding folder and then add the partitions to metadata as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE seesaw ADD PARTITION(address='Memphis');
ALTER TABLE seesaw ADD PARTITION(address='kolkata');
```

Refer this article for a simple example of how to do this - [hive-external-table-with-partitions](http://blog.zhengdong.me/2012/02/22/hive-external-table-with-partitions/)